# The class 'Icons' doesn't have an unnamed constructor

Tags: flutter, dart

I've been trying to build a bottom navigation bar when I came across this error. Here's the code

```
 import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class NavPage extends StatefulWidget {
  const NavPage({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  State<NavPage> createState() => _NavPageState();
}

class _NavPageState extends State<NavPage> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      bottomNavigationBar: BottomNavigationBar(
        items: [
          BottomNavigationBarItem(icon: Icons(Icons.local_movies),
            activeIcon: const Icon(Icons.local_movies),
            label: 'Movies'
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You are doing a typing mistake here use `Icon()` to get the constructor.

```dart
BottomNavigationBarItem(icon: Icon(Icons.local_movies),
```

Answer (score 0):

change it to:

```
  BottomNavigationBarItem(icon: Icon(Icons.local_movies),
```